# Does Apple recommend using class extensions or variable blocks in implementation?

Tags: objective-c

Apple's doc mentions two ways to create private variables, namely property and ivar, but it does not say which is the preferred way. Which one is Apple's recommended approach or are they equally good in Apple's view?

```
 @interface MyClass ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *prop;
 @end
```

or

```
@implementation MyClass {
   NSObject *_prop;
}
```

Note - I am not asking for personal opinion, but Apple's recommendation. There are similar discussion on this but most have been viewed from personal opinion with no clarification on why one is better than the other and which way Apple advocates (though 99% of Apple sample code uses property)

Answer (score 4):

You should always use `@properties` because they are safer (e.g. they contain the thread-safe access protection for atomic properties, etc).

And you should also always access properties via their getter/setter instead of directly accessing the instance variables (except in init methods).

As for Apple's recommendations:

- Apple engineers answered that at some talks during past WWDC. Sorry no written reference, but I can confirm that they recommend properties over instance variables
- In Apple's ["Programming With Objective-C" Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html), they mention that you should always prefer using properties over instance variables:

> Although it’s best practice for an object to access its own properties using accessor methods or dot syntax, it’s possible to access the instance variable directly from any of the instance methods in a class implementation.
>   [...]
>   In general, you should use accessor methods or dot syntax for property access even if you’re accessing an object’s properties from within its own implementation, in which case you should use self
>   [...]
>   The exception to this rule is when writing initialization, deallocation or custom accessor methods

- Actually in such Programming Guides, like [here where they describe the anatomy of an ObjC class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW7), they never mention instance variables and explain how to create them, they only explain properties, so that's a pretty strong indicator that they try to enforce them anyway.